# How can you capture multiple arguments weakly in a Swift closure?

Tags: swift, closures, weak-references

Is there a way to capture multiple arguments weakly in a swift closure?  I know this is the syntax to capture one argument weakly:

```
{ [weak arg]
    arg.doSomething()
}
```

How can I do this for two objects that I wish to capture weakly?

Answer (score 107):

From [Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) in "The Swift Programming Language" (emphasis added):

> *Closure Expression*
>   ...
>   A closure expression can explicitly specify the values that it
>   captures from the surrounding scope using a capture list. A capture
>   list is written as a **comma separated list** surrounded by square
>   brackets, before the list of parameters. If you use a capture list,
>   you must also use the `in` keyword, even if you omit the parameter
>   names, parameter types, and return type.

Example:

```
{
    [weak arg1, weak arg2] in 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Always to the rescue Martin :)