# Declare weak in nested closure

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

During the following 0.5 second delay, the tableViewManager might be deallocated. I want to ensure that the textView is weak when interacting with it inside the nested closure. How would I go about this?

```
tableViewManager.textViewDidBeginEditing = { [weak self] textView, indexPath in
    asyncAfter(seconds: 0.5) {
        let value = textView.tag // touched here
        self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Please stop supplying answers about how to make self weak. This question is not asking about 'self'. The textView. The teeeeexttt viiieeewww.

Comment: you should be able to add `[weak self]` after the `asyncAfter`

Comment: I want to touch the textView parameter. Not self.

Comment: `textView` won't cause a retain cycle. Passed parameters in closures don't cause retain cycles at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response @vadian. A full answer with a supporting explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I update my answer. I think this could be a duplicate of [How can you capture multiple arguments weakly in a Swift closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28015455/10830091)

Comment: I can't find a reference. But it has been mentioned in a WWDC video about `NSKeyValueObservation` explicitly that the observed object is passed as a parameter to avoid a retain cycle. And GCD closures don't cause retain cycles either.

Comment: @vadian I'm confused when you say 'passed as a parameter'. of course it's passed as a parameter. it's a parameter!

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9723

Comment: You already declared `textView` as `weak`. From that point on you'll always have a weak reference to `textView`, unless you downgrade it to `unowned`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular syntax:

```
tableViewManager.textViewDidBeginEditing = { [weak self] textView, indexPath in
    // textView is strong here
    asyncAfter(seconds: 0.5) { [weak textView] in
        // textView is weak here
        let value = textView?.tag // touched here
        self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

Try to use container to avoid that compiler bug:

```
class WeakLink<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

tableViewManager.textViewDidBeginEditing = { [weak self] textView, indexPath in
    let weakTextView = WeakLink(textView)
    asyncAfter(seconds: 0.5) {
        // textView is weak here
        let textView = weakTextView.value
        let value = textView?.tag // touched here
        self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: get segmentation fault 11 for this https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9723

Comment: @Jonesy , I've edited the answer. It should work without crash.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

if you put [weak self] in the top closure it will be weak for all of the nested ones... and then consider safe unwrapping it if you do not want it optional in the main closure.

```
tableViewManager.textViewDidBeginEditing = { [weak self] textView, indexPath in
  guard let self = self else { return } // optional...
  asyncAfter(seconds: 0.5) {
     let value = textView.tag // touched here
     self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I think if tableViewManager will be deallocated the closure will never be called... right? so no need to worry about "textView" being optional. it is a closure parameter... so you can set it only in closure declaration.

ARC will delete the closure automatically as soon as the tableViewManager reference is gone.

Comment: Again, the question is not about self or the tableView. Read the question a little closer please.

Comment: oh I see, I think if tableViewManager will be deallocated the closure will never be called... right? so no need to worry about "textView" being optional. it is a closure parameter... so you can set it only in closure declaration

Comment: Believe is not the most productive way of proofing something, test it first, remove manually the reference to tableViewManager... you can set another asyncAfter to do that...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. This has now been recognised as [a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9723).